# Pandas Df - Change one value to uppercase

Tags: python, pandas

I am not sure why the loop below does not work. The upper function makes the string an uppercase value, but I can not get it to save the new, uppercase value in the df.

Thanks for your help!

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['Ticker']=='ZZzzz':
        #print("yes'")
        df.iloc[i]['Ticker']=df.iloc[i]['Ticker'].upper()
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['Ticker'] == 'ZZzzz', 'Ticker'] = 'ZZZZZ'`?

Comment: did any of the answers solved your question ?

Comment: Thank you for your help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b','bb','cccc'], 'Ticker': ['aAAa','ZZzzz','c','CccC']})

df['Ticker'] = np.where(df.Ticker == 'ZZzzz', df.Ticker.str.upper(), df.Ticker)

      col1 Ticker
0     a   aAAa
1     b  ZZZZZ
2    bb      c
3  cccc   CccC
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your dataframe change at all? If I exactly copy your code with my own dataframe, it does work and it ouputs the uppercase z's.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b','bb','cccc'], 'Ticker': ['aAAa','ZZzzz','c','CccC']})


+----+-------+--------+
|    | col1  | Ticker |
+----+-------+--------+
| 0  | a     | aAAa   |
| 1  | b     | ZZzzz  |
| 2  | bb    | c      |
| 3  | cccc  | CccC   |
+----+-------+--------+
```

When applying your script:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['Ticker']=='ZZzzz':
        print(i)
        df.iloc[i]['Ticker']=df.iloc[i]['Ticker'].upper() 


+----+-------+--------+
|    | col1  | Ticker |
+----+-------+--------+
| 0  | a     | aAAa   |
| 1  | b     | ZZZZZ  |
| 2  | bb    | c      |
| 3  | cccc  | CccC   |
+----+-------+--------+
```

It could be that it is in your if statement (is it right the first 2 z-characters are uppercase in your dataframe?).
You can try to add print(i) to your loop to see if that works. If it doesn't print the value of i any time, it does not work because the if loop is skipped for every i.

Hope this helps!